Dynamically change backgroud of a grid Xamarin
I want to change the background color of a grid based on what is the status. I made a converter which takes status and based of what it is changes color but for some reason after debugging it doesnt seem to enter the converter at all. The converter works when i set the waiting color to something else. i think the problem is with dynamically changing  the color after pressing a button.
private void CompleteExercise(Exercise exercise)
 {
     exercise.Status = Status.Completed;
 } // this command works btw

<Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToBackgroundColorConverter}}">
   <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Complete" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CompleteExerciseCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=Workouts}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
</Grid>

public class StatusToBackgroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Status status)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case Status.Waiting:
                    return Color.Transparent;
                case Status.InProgress:
                    return Color.Yellow; 
                case Status.Completed:
                    return Color.Green; 
                default:
                    return Color.Transparent;
            }
        }
        return Color.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


could you include more details (help people to help you) StatusToBackgroundColorConverter instance and Status property definition ? what is your viewmodel?...

@Cfun what exectly should i post

Status property and in whcih file it is defined, relevant viewmodel code, where are you setting the bindingcontext of your page.. any other relevant detail that could help us to understand your issue

Based on your code, I tried to achieve this function on my side, you can refer to the following code.
1.Please make your item model inherit class ObservableObject and add [ObservableProperty] for property Status Status;
public partial class Item: ObservableObject
{
   //For the sake of simplicity, omit the other codes
    [ObservableProperty]
    Status status;
}

2.please set a margin for the outer Grid, otherwise you won't see the background color change, as the Button inside the Grid will obscure the background of the Grid.
 <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource myStatusToBgConverter}}"  Grid.Column="4"  Padding="5">
                                <Button Text="Complete" BackgroundColor="Blue" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CompleteExerciseCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                            </Grid>
 </Grid>

3.Please refer to the following code on my demo:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiMvvmListApp0407.Models"
             xmlns:converts="clr-namespace:MauiMvvmListApp0407.Converter"
             x:Class="MauiMvvmListApp0407.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <converts:StatusToBackgroundColorConverter x:Key="myStatusToBgConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Frame Grid.Row="6"  BackgroundColor="#B1C0C9" BorderColor="#7989A3">
            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                  BackgroundColor="Gray"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Item">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   FontSize="17"
                                   FontFamily="OCRA"
                                   TextColor="Black"/>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!--//For the sake of simplicity, omit the other codes -->

                                <Grid BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource myStatusToBgConverter}}"  Grid.Column="4"  Padding="5">
                                    <Button Text="Complete" BackgroundColor="Blue" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.CompleteExerciseCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=listView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>

                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </Frame>
</ContentPage>

Note:
Please install nuget CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.
